# JavaScript basic code tell what is my wrong with it

Tags: javascript, function

Hello coders please let me know where i went wrong and why toFixed() method is not working. I learning javascript for the first time so i dont have much idea about it. Please soime one help me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <input id="numb">

    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>

      function myFunction() {
        var x, y;
        x = document.getElementById('numb').value;
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=x.toFixed(3);
      }

    </script>

    </body>
    </html> 

//***Here toFixed() Method not working***
```

Comment: @Innervisions [`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

Answer (score 2):

Ok you have to convert the string number to float before using toFixed()

```js
 function myFunction() {
        var x, y;
        x = document.getElementById('numb').value;
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML= parseFloat(x).toFixed(2);
      }
```

```html
    <input id="numb">

    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>

    <p id="demo">hui</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your x is not number and you can't use toFixed function.
You need to convert x to a number first. For this please use something of this code

```
x = +document.getElementById('numb').value;
x = +x;     
x = parseInt(x);
```

Comment: Thanks, It was helpful for my case

Answer (score 1):

convert the String to int

```
x = document.getElementById('numb').value;
```

to

```
x = parseInt(document.getElementById('numb').value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct two things:

1. Make the input type as `number`
2. use `parseFloat(x)` before you apply the `toFixed()` method.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x, y;
  x = document.getElementById('numb').value;
  debugger
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = parseFloat(x).toFixed(3);
}
```

```html
<input id="numb" type="number">
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

`x` is not a number object here. That is why JS doesn't find the method attached to it.

You can read further on this here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <input id="numb">

    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>

      function myFunction() {
        var x, y;
        x = document.getElementById('numb').value;
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML= Number.parseFloat(x).toFixed(2);
      }

    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To understand the problem you need to check what is type of variable x

`console.log(typeof x)`

You will find out its a string. While toFixed() works only on Number types. So you need to convert x string to "Number Type" using parseInt(x) or parseFloat(x) right before using toFixed().

```
function myFunction() {
  var x, y;
  x = document.getElementById('numb').value;
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = parseFloat(x).toFixed(3);
}
```